# How to search and replace string in excel (.xls) file using Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlutils

i am trying to use search and replace string in excel file (xls), actually - i need to find string and add before prefix * .
For example

[image: 1]

But i am getting a error:

```
LVdemact = {'two': two_replaced, 'six': six_replaced, 'five': five_replaced}
NameError: name 'two_replaced' is not defined
```

Code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlsxwriter

rb = open_workbook("template.xlsx")

# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Updated_Workbook1.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

s_orig = rb.sheet_by_index(0)

LVdemact = {'two': two_replaced, 'six': six_replaced, 'five': five_replaced,}

for row in range(s_orig.nrows):
    for col in range(s_orig.ncols):
        if s_orig.cell(row,col).value in LVdemact:
            # s.write(row, col, LVdemact[item])
            ws.write(row, col, LVdemact[s_orig.cell(row,col).value])
        else:
            ws.write(row, col, s_orig.cell(row,col).value)
wb.close()
```

Comment: You need to at least add something like `two_replaced = "two_replaced"` before you define `LVdemact`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the line - `LVdemact = {'two': two_replaced, 'six': six_replaced, 'five': five_replaced,}`

variables `two_replaced`, `six_replaced` and `five_replaced` are not defined. Do you want this to be a string ? then define this in this way -

```
LVdemact = {'two': 'two_replaced', 'six': 'six_replaced', 'five': 'five_replaced'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame() # Your dataframe

for column in df.select_dtypes('object'):
    df[column] = df[column].str.replace('toreplace','newword')
```

Comment: Once you replace the string in the data frame, how do you write back to your excel sheet though?

Comment: `df.to_excel('<filename>')` sometimes you need to add engine also. i mostly pre install openpyxl and add as argument.